# Bezier curves of grade n

Tags: c++, c++11, graphics

I made a function which creates [Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) of grade n. What do you think?

```
float interpolate(float n1, float n2, float prec)
{
    return n1 + ((n2-n1) * prec);
}

std::vector<Vector2f> make_bezier(const std::vector<Vector2f>& anchors, double accuracy=10000.0)
{
    if(anchors.size()<=2)
        return anchors;

    std::vector<Vector2f> end;
    end.push_back(anchors[0]);

    for(float i=0.f; i<1.f; i+=1.f/accuracy)
    {
        std::vector<Vector2f> temp;
        for(unsigned int j=1; j<anchors.size(); ++j)
            temp.push_back(Vector2f(interpolate(anchors[j-1].x, anchors[j].x, i),
                                    interpolate(anchors[j-1].y, anchors[j].y, i)));

        while(temp.size()>1)
        {
            std::vector<Vector2f> temp2;

            for(unsigned int j=1; j<temp.size(); ++j)
                temp2.push_back(Vector2f(interpolate(temp[j-1].x, temp[j].x, i),
                                         interpolate(temp[j-1].y, temp[j].y, i)));
            temp = temp2;
        }
        end.push_back(temp[0]);
    }

    return end;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a few comments:

```
std::vector<Vector2f> make_bezier(const std::vector<Vector2f>& anchors, double accuracy=10000.0)
```

You're using `float` for all your other floating point variables. Unless there's some *really* good reason to use `double` here (for `accuracy`) I'd consider changing it to a `float` as well.

```
std::vector<Vector2f> end;
end.push_back(anchors[0]);

for(float i=0.f; i<1.f; i+=1.f/accuracy)
```

I'd write this a bit differently. As it stands, `i` can accumulate rounding errors from one iteration of the loop to the next. I'd prefer to do something like:

```
for (int j=0; j<accuracy; j++) {
    float i = 1.0f/j;
    // ...
```

This way, each value of `i` is computed independently, and rounding from one iteration doesn't affect its value in the next.

```
    std::vector<Vector2f> temp;
    for(unsigned int j=1; j<anchors.size(); ++j)
        temp.push_back(Vector2f(interpolate(anchors[j-1].x, anchors[j].x, i),
                                interpolate(anchors[j-1].y, anchors[j].y, i)));
```

Literally *all* your calls to `interolate` (at least in this code) happen in pairs. That being the case, I think I'd rewrite it a bit to take a couple of `vector2f`s as parameters, and return a `vector2f` containing the interpolation on both the `x` and `y` components of the inputs. It also uses `i` as a third input. My immediate reaction would be to define `interpolate` as a lambda that captured `i`, and took the other two parameters as inputs.

```
vector2f interpolate(vector2f in1, vector2f const &in2) { 
    in1.x = /* ... */;
    in1.y = /* ... */;
    return in1;
}
```

With that in place, the loop above can be reduced to a fairly simple application of `std::transform`, something like this:

```
 std::transform(anchors.begin(), anchors.end(), 
                anchors.begin()+1, 
                std::back_inserter(temp));
```

Of course, pretty much the same would happen here:

```
        for(unsigned int j=1; j<temp.size(); ++j)
            temp2.push_back(Vector2f(interpolate(temp[j-1].x, temp[j].x, i),
                                     interpolate(temp[j-1].y, temp[j].y, i)));
```

...as well.

Answer (score 10):

Just a few notes:

- You could improve readability by adding whitespace between operators.

  For instance, in the `for` loop statement:

  ```
  for (float i = 0.f; i < 1.f; i += 1.f/accuracy) {}
  ```

  For this as well, I would have a constant in place of the `1.f/accuracy` to avoid performing the division operation each time (it's slow).  Instead, you'll only be performing addition each time.

  Consider something like this:

  ```
  const float stepsize = 1.f / accuracy;

  for (float i = 0.f; i < 1.f; i += stepsize) {}
  ```
- With an `std::vector`, you can use [`front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) to get the reference to the first element instead of using the index `0`:

  ```
  end.push_back(anchors.front());
  ```
- Prefer to use [`std::size_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/c-vectorintsize-type) when incrementing through an STL container.  This guarantees that you can access every element of any container size, whereas an `unsigned int` or another integer type may not be large enough.

  Due to its length, this can be declared before the loop.

  ```
  std::vector<Vector2f>::size_type j;

  for (j = 1; j != temp.size(); ++j) {}
  ```

Comment: Also I would not calculate 1.f/accuracy 10000 times. Maybe a variable float stepsize = 1.f/accuracy should be introduced.

Comment: @MarcelBlanck: I've missed that as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the things which already have been noted:

You duplicate the interpolation loop in your body which violates DRY. The easy fix for that is to copy `anchors` into `temp`.

Also rather than assigning `temp2` to `temp` which copies the vector you could use [`vector::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) which swaps the contents of the two vectors in constant time.

So your main body can be written as:

```
for (float k = 0.f; k < accuracy; ++k)
{
    float i = k / accuracy;

    std::vector<Vector2f> temp(anchors);

    while (temp.size() > 1)
    {
        std::vector<Vector2f> temp2;

        for (unsigned int j = 1; j < temp.size(); ++j)
            temp2.push_back(Vector2f(interpolate(temp[j-1].x, temp[j].x, i),
                                     interpolate(temp[j-1].y, temp[j].y, i)));
        temp.swap(temp2);
    }
    end.push_back(temp.front());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm you are using works, but it will exhibit very poor performance as you increase the order of your Bézier curve. Let's say that you want to render `m` points and that you have `n` anchors, you are computing `n-1` + `n-2` + ... + `1` interpolations for *every* rendered point. So we are talking about an O(n²m) algorithm.

If performance matters, you'll have to consider using the general formula with the binomial coefficients. The binomial coefficients can be precomputed so we can consider that they are given for free. Then for each rendered point you only need to traverse the list of anchors once, yielding an O(nm) algorithm.

Comment: this seems like a good point, I would like to see more code in the review, but I think this fits.